# Lookup Field searchbar

Tags: search, lookup-column

I have this lookup field which is coupled to a customlist of artists.
I use this lookup field as a column for another list. So when someone creates
a listitem in this second list he or she can choose one item of the
previousely mentioned artistlist in the form of a lookup. Well,
after a while this artist list will get bigger and bigger. So when there 
are 500 artists our customer has to scroll through an anoyingly hugh list.
Is it possible to add a search function to the newitem page to search in this lookup list? 
Greets Fabian

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint Server, the best way to handle this feature is to move away from lookup fields and use a managed meta-data field with an associated termset.  The termset will provide a type-ahead feature, but also a lot more capabilities around managing the list long term versus a linked list and lookup field.

You can likely pre-populate all of the existing values using a PowerShell script helping with the transition from the old to the new field so that it doesn't have to be manual if you have thousands of records.